# What kind of mortar and pestle will be strong enough for grinding date pits?

Tags: mortar-and-pestle

So, I need to crush date pits, I have a marble mortar and pestle, but I don't think it is strong enough for this job. Has anyone any suggestion?

Comment: Do you only want suggestions that are a type of mortar and pestle? I think many people utilize mechanical devices like grinders/processors etc...

Comment: My dad always used his shop vice for cracking macadamia nut shells. Not sure how well that would work for an application where you want the thing you're crushing, not the thing *inside* the thing you're crushing.

Comment: @Catija I am looking for a product suggestion or advice about the hardest material: e.g., is granite the best material for hard mortar+pestle? or is cast iron best? There are many options on amazon. But I don't want to buy another mortar+pestle just for this specific use and later find it unusable.

Comment: @Marti yes, i want the grounded date. In traditional medicine, grounding has a different effect than "cutting" with a food processor. The powdered pit of some dates (`Ajwah`) is considered a medicine for heart disease.

Comment: What do you mean strong enough? Do you mean the material won't stand up to the force required, or you aren't strong enough to use the mortar and pestle to do it?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/c/presstube

Comment: @GdD the material should be strong enough to withstand my force.

Comment: @Sobachatina that was a nice waste of time :) but that machine will be too big for my kitchen.

Answer (score 1):

If your seeds have been dried a marble mortar and pestle works quite well. I would suggest making a disk the circumference of the mortar out of cardboard to surround the neck of the pestle. It will limit the amount of dust that goes in the air.